# When adding another Google login, user should get routed to Google Multi-Login screen

Tags: feature-request, login, google-openid

[ORIGINAL POST](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357667/how-do-i-add-my-work-google-account-to-my-main-so-account?noredirect=1#comment521756_357667)

> I went ahead and added my work account to my personal account's
>   chrome session and then revisited the google auth link from my main SO
>   account, and this time it gave me the 2 options, and I successfully
>   added it. However, I don't think it should work this way! You should
>   get that screen that either allows you to select an existing logged-in
>   account, or add a new one.
>
> @RudyOnRails Yeah, I agree. Looks like there's a parameter we can pass
>   along for that, though I'm not sure off the top of my head how much
>   work it'd be for us to start doing that for the "add login" path.
>   Could you do me a favor and write up a quick feature-request for this
>   so we can track it easier? Thanks! – Adam Lear♦ 20 hours ago

Comment: "That screen" is generally known as the Google Multi-Login.